# Simplify a sum of n products

Tags: summation

Given the following sum formula:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (i\cdot 2^{n-i}) $

Can you help me out to a simplify the formula and provide an formula without a Sigma sign?

I know that I cannot just split the Sigma like that:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (i\cdot 2^{n-i}) \ne (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i) \cdot (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2^{n-i}) $

I am wondering if there is something else I can do

Comment: Did you write it correctly?  As written it is just $2^{n-1}\times \sum_{i=1}^ni$

Comment: @lulu sorry, there was a mistake in the question. I have edited the question. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Expressions of this sort can be analyzed via geometric series.  For an infinite version, note that $f(x)=\frac {1}{1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i$ and differentiation yields $f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ix^{i-1}$ which is akin to yours (you'll need to work with partial sums for the geometric series, of course).

Comment: Already asked zillion times.

Comment: Let the sum be $S$. Calculate $S = 2S - S$ by rearranging indices.

Comment: This is not a sum of $n$ products. It is a sum of products where the first term consists of $n$ products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following xbh's hint:
$$S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (i\cdot 2^{n-i})=\color{red}{1\cdot 2^{n-1}}+2\cdot 2^{n-2}+\cdots+\color{blue}{(n-1)\cdot 2^1}+n\cdot 2^0\\
2S=2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (i\cdot 2^{n-i})=1\cdot 2^{n}+\color{red}{2\cdot 2^{n-1}}+\cdots+(n-1)\cdot 2^2+\color{blue}{n\cdot 2^1}.$$
Subtract $2S-S$:
$$S=2^n+\color{red}{2^{n-1}}+\cdots+\color{blue}{2}-n=\frac{2(2^n-1)}{2-1}-n=2^{n+1}-2-n. $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$1\cdot2^{n-1}+2\cdot2^{n-2}+\cdots n\cdot2^0
\\=0\cdot2^{n-1}+1\cdot2^{n-2}+\cdots (n-1)\cdot2^0+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\cdots2^0
\\=\frac{1\cdot2^{n-1}+2\cdot2^{n-2}+\cdots n\cdot2^0}2-\frac{n\cdot2^0}2+2^n-1.$$

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this hint ??

Comment: It looks great to me.

Comment: why was this hint downvoted ?? +1

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the hint! So there is a small arithmetic sequence for every item in the main sequence! Huh! never thought about that

Comment: Maybe personal attack here…?

Comment: @Stasel: I am not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: +1 for encouraging the OP to attempt and improve. Just in case, I never downvoted this post.